# How to pass GetIntent data from Activity to ViewModel

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have **LoaiSpActivity** , **DanhSachActivity** and **DanhSachSpViewModel** for **DanhSachActivity**

So in **LoaiSpActivity**: i had putExtra a key & value called **"idloaivatpham"**.
In **DanhSachActivity**:  i have a function to get that key & value from key **"idloaivatpham"** into **idkiem**.
In DanhSachSpViewModel: i have a function to get data from Server but it will base on a Key & value **(idkiem)** to return data (in **hash getParam()**).
So now i want to pass the idkiem from DanhSachActivity to DanhSachSpViewModel but when i put  **idkiem = getIntent().getIntExtra("idloaivatpham", -1);** in that ViewModel i got a error in getIntent(). So anyone have the solution please help me. Sorry for my english not very well.

Here is my code

> **LoaiSpActivity**

```
 private void CatchOnItemListView(List<LoaiVatPham> loaiVatPhams) {
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            switch (i){
                case 0:
                    if(CheckConnection.haveNetworkConnection(getApplicationContext())){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoaiSpActivity.this, DanhSachSpActivity.class);
                        //truyen du lieu giua cac activity
                        intent.putExtra("idloaivatpham",loaiVatPhams.get(i).getId());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        CheckConnection.ShowToast(getApplicationContext(),"Check Internet Connection");
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if(CheckConnection.haveNetworkConnection(getApplicationContext())){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoaiSpActivity.this, DanhSachSpActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("idloaivatpham",loaiVatPhams.get(i).getId());
                        startActivity(intent);
```

> **DanhSachActivity**

```
  private void GetIdLoaiSanPham() {
    idkiem = getIntent().getIntExtra("idloaivatpham", -1);
    Log.d("giatriloaisanpham", idkiem + "");
}
```

> DanhSachSpViewModel

```
 }) {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
            param.put("idloaivatpham", String.valueOf(idkiem));
            return param;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

> My error when i put getIntent in ViewModel

```
 idkiem = getIntent().getIntExtra("idloaivatpham", -1); // This have error at getIntent().
```